# PHP Object Array - Check if array key exists

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following object array returned from a soap call:

```
$result = $this->soapClient->__soapCall($method, $arguments);

var_dump($result);


object(stdClass)#4 (1) {
    ["Jobs_GetResult"]=> object(stdClass)#5 (3) {
        ["Jobs"]=> array(4) {
              [0]=> object(stdClass)#7 (19) {
                    ["JobID"]=> int(55082846)
                    ["JobName"]=> string(18) "Fix xyz"
              } 

        }
        ["Errors"]=> object(stdClass)#10 (2) {
             ["Result"]=> int(0)
             ["Message"]=> string(0) "" 
        }
        ["RecordCount"]=> int(1) 
    }
}
```

I want to check if there are any errors - this is easy when the parent array key is known e.g:

```
if($result->Jobs_GetResult->Errors->Result > 0){
     // display message
}
```

The issue is I do not know what the name of the top level array key is going to be for most of the calls as i'm using a generic method - in the above example it's `Jobs_GetResult` so the above would work.

In instances where the top level array key is unknown how do I check if there are any errors returned?

In general the name of the parent array key is usually the name of the method call with `Result` appended to it. so I was thinking doing something along the lines of:

```
 if($result->$method . 'Result'->Errors->Result > 0){
     // display message
 }
```

But obviously the above syntax is incorrect. Any one know how to output value of `$method` and chain it to `$result` and append it with `Result`

Is there any other way I can check if the Errors array result is greater than 1 without knowing what the parent array key is?

Comment: Maybe a simple foreach can do the job? If you do `foreach($result as $key => $value) {}` you can get the error in `$value->Errors->Result` no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$result = $this->soapClient->__soapCall($method, $arguments);

$firstKey = key($result);

if (!empty($firstKey) && !empty($result->{$firstKey}->Errors->Result)) {
    // display message
}
```

Comment: Can you use `key()` on an object? It doesn't look like it according to the manual.

Comment: You can cast as `Std` object to an array first then it will work as you expect.

Comment: @jeroen You dont actually need to cast it, just tried it on an object and it works. I was sceptical also

Comment: @RiggsFolly Nice, I didn't know that. Just tried it myself :-)

Comment: If you are sceptical, just cast $result to an array: `$firstKey = key((array)$result);`

Comment: Daniel I was sceptical and that is why I tested it. Once I found it worked I upvoted your answer.